# Calling Zip Code -- Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have both the phone number and address (including the zipcode) in the same TextView.  I want the phone number to be clickable to call; however, this is making the zip code also clickable to make a phone call.  How do I make it no longer clickable without creating another TextView?  Thanks!

```
tvInfo.setText(Html.fromHtml("John Smith<br>123 Fake Street<br>Faketown, FK 12345<br><b>(804) 932-3300</b><br>"));

Linkify.addLinks(tvInfo, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```

Comment: Watch out, you had an extra quote in your top line. I removed it, but please check that it's not in your actual code.

Comment: Oops. no not in my code.  Thanks tho.  I just changed it real quick to make it fake street and such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android will regard digits with count >=5 as phone numbers. so I think there will be at least 2 solutions:

1)a simple work around : if you are sure the length of phone numbers is more than 5, for example, at least 6 digits, you could make some work around:

```
private final static int MY_PHONE_NUMBER_MINIMUM_DIGITS = 6;

Linkify.addLinks(main, Patterns.PHONE, "tel:", new Linkify.MatchFilter() {
     public final boolean acceptMatch(CharSequence s, int start, int end) {
       int digitCount = 0;

       for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
         if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
           digitCount++;
           if (digitCount >= MY_PHONE_NUMBER_MINIMUM_DIGITS ) {
             return true;
         }
       }
     }
      return false;
    }
  }, Linkify.sPhoneNumberTransformFilter);
```

this workaround is based on android source code of Linkify, in Linkify, the method:

```
gatherLinks(links, text, Patterns.PHONE, 
            new String[] { "tel:" },
            sPhoneNumberMatchFilter, sPhoneNumberTransformFilter);
```

will be called, while sPhoneNumberMatchFilter will filter the digits less than 5:

```
public static final MatchFilter sPhoneNumberMatchFilter = new MatchFilter() {
    public final boolean acceptMatch(CharSequence s, int start, int end) {
      int digitCount = 0;

      for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
          digitCount++;
          if (digitCount >= PHONE_NUMBER_MINIMUM_DIGITS/*=5*/) {
            return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

};

so we just replace the "PHONE_NUMBER_MINIMUM_DIGITS" with 6

2)a more complicated solution is, if your phone numbers are in a more specific format for example, must be something like "(xxx)xxx-xxxx", you could use your own pattern to replace the Patterns.PHONE, to extract and apply links of phone numbers more accurately

Comment: oops. it worked cuz i only put a 4 digit zip code in my example code. its actually a 5 digit code. my mistake...i have adjusted it